# Just creating directories using multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system

I'm coding in Java but I think it is more general problem outside Java.

I want to know if it is safe to create directories using multiple threads.

In Java, I can use `new File(...).mkdirs()` to make directories.

What happens if two threads execute `new File(...).mkdirs()` (almost) at the same time?

More precisely,

Thread 1 executes `new File("%ROOT%/a/b/c/d).mkdirs();`

and

Thread 2 executes `new File("%ROOT%/a/b/c/e).mkdirs();`

Is this situation safe or not?

If not, what problems can occur?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: It’s safe, but a (non-SSD) hard drive can only write to one place at a time, so disk access doesn’t parallelize well.  You probably won’t see much of a performance gain.  Also, [the java.io.File class is obsolete;](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks)  you should be using [Files.createDirectories](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) instead.

Answer (score 1):

**It is safe.**

The OS will simply create the directories from the instructions *it sees as the first one* and then only create the missing directories from the second one.

You just have no guarantee on which directories will be created first but the instructions run concurrently you probably do not care!

Comment: So don't I need to worry about anything?

Comment: No, as long as your OS can be trusted ;-)